# Assigning value to NPZ file

Tags: numpy

Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work:

Step 1) Create a simple NPZ file

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.zeros((3,2), dtype=np.double)
np.savez('npzfile.npz', field1=a1)
```

Step 2) Open NPZ file and try to assign a value to it

```
npzfile = np.load('npzfile.npz')
npzfile['field1'][0,0] = 3.2
print npzfile['field1']
```

This gives me the following output:

```
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]]
```

In other words, trying to assign `3.2` to the array did nothing. Why?

Comment: You can see this as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/71183327/16733101

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears as if the npzfile pseudo-dict (actually a `numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile`) is not writeable. If you set a separate variable to the array, you can write to it:

```
a = npzfile['field1']
a[0,0] = 3.2
print a
```

Interestingly, unlike a normal array `np.may_share_memory(a, npzfile['field1'])` returns `False`, whereas if you set `b=a`, `np.may_share_memory(a, b)` returns `True`. Extracting the `field1` array from the npzfile pseudo-dict into a new variable is creating a copy, which is not the normal behavior if it was a standard numpy ndarray. I'm not familiar with the internals of the `numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile` type, but I'm guessing even though `type(npzfile['field1'])` is an `ndarray`, its memory is being treated differently.

Comment: Thanks Josh. From the source code [link] (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.1/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L133) it appears NpzFile uses lazy-loading and there's no `setitem`. I'm guessing that's the reason?

Comment: @JoshAdel the thing is that `np.load('file.npz')` is not loading the file into memory until you do `a = npzfile['key']`, and therefore it creates a copy everytime you call `__getitem__()` (it reads from disk and dumps into memory)

Comment: even if you can assign to `a`, the new value seems not to be reflected in `npzfile['field1']`

Comment: @AndreHolzner Yes. It shouldn't. You need to assign it, play with it, and again save it to npz if you want.

Answer (score 6):

Hopefully not stating the too-obvious here, but I create a `dict` from it:

```
a = dict(npzfile)
```

Now you have a dictionary that you can add to and later `np.savez` to a file.  I would assume this loads everything into memory which may or may not be what you want (based on @Saullo Castro 's comment above.)